# Is there any sample way to import PDF file to DB2 blob field?

Tags: db2

I have a table that contains a Blob field to store a PDF or image (jpeg, gif, ...) file. There's a Java EE application to do this and it works fine.

But, sometimes I need to insert or update the Blob field via a command.

Is there any simple way to do this without coding? I'm looking for a pure command or some kind of tool.

DB2 is v9 at AIX and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have DB2 handy right now but I think I can point you in the correct direction:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILENAME="$1"
HEX=`xxd -p $FILENAME | tr -d '\n'`

echo insert into $2 \($3\) values \(cast\(X\'$HEX\' as blob\( $4 \)  \) \);
```

The idea is to use [xxd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) to create proper hexadecimal string of your file. (AIX has xxd installed unless it is broken.) The hexadecimal string can then be used with the db2 command line processor ("db2") in SQL queries. All you have to do is to [cast the hexadecimal string to blob](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008478.html).

The script I gave you will print out correct SQL query for testing. Fix it to match your DDL and other requirements. Then change the echo command to db2 command and you should have a working utility:

```
./myscript myfile mytable myblob myblobsize
```